# Can IntelliJ be configured to show EJB-2 callers when using "Call Hierarchy"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I like to use the Navigate -> Call Hierarchy (`Ctrl-Alt-H`) command a lot to show the static call tree to a method in my EJB-2 app.

Unfortunately, this function does not detect callers to a Bean method that go via the EJB Local interface.

For example, if I call `EjbLocalObject.methodCall()` this will be dispatched by the EJB-container to `LocalObjectBean.methodCall()`.

If I use "Goto Implementation" (`Ctrl-Alt-B` or `Ctrl-Alt-LeftMouse`) then IntelliJ will navigate into the Bean method so it obviously knows about EJB-2 call dispatching.

Is there some configuration or plugin I need to set to enable "Call Hierarchy" to follow EJB-2 method dispatch? (I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 11.0.2)